# What the complete list of item options for an Android Theme

Tags: android, themes

If I generate a android application with the Android Studio, I got this `themes.xml` file:

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.Basic" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

If I understand correctly what's going on here, this theme uses the values from the parent theme `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar` and overrides the items listed on the file.

Supose I want create a theme but do not want inherits the values from another theme, where I can find the complete list of items options for create a theme? And what each item corresponds in the application interface.

Comment: "Supose I want create a theme but do not want inherits the values from another theme" -- that may or may not be an option for you. The requirements and options for a theme comes from whatever uses the theme. In your case, you are using [the Material Components for Android](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android), and that library will have [certain requirements for your theme](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#appcompat-or-materialcomponents-themes).

Comment: If I do not use the Material Components for Android, is it possible then create a theme without a parent theme like the one in the question?

Comment: If you avoid inheriting from `AppCompatActivity`, you can create a theme with no `parent`. Note that there are two ways to express theme inheritance: `parent` and dot notation. So, even without `parent`, a theme named `Theme.Basic` inherits from the overall root theme named `Theme`.